# state change does not cause re-render in function component

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

In the React Native 0.63.2 app, there is a function component `DisplayImages` to present the images uploaded. When the images order were changed in state `Imgs`,  the `DisplayImages` is expected to re-render. Here is the code:

```
import DisplayImages from "./DisplayImages";

export default function Itie({navigation}) { //<<==this is the parent component which calls child DisplayImages
    const [imgs, setImgs] = useState(); //<<==image array to display

      return(
         <MyAccordion 
                            title={"Image"} 
                            absPosition={false} 
                            screenSize={{width:screen_width, height:((imgs && imgs.length>9) ? screen_width+(screen_width/3)*(Math.ceil(((imgs.length-9)%3)/3)):screen_width)}} 
                            ref= {refImg}
                        >
                            <DisplayImages pics={imgs} deleteImage={deleteImage} updateImage={(new_img)=> {setImgs(new_img);console.log("in updateImage", new_img.map((it) => it.fileName))}} swipeImage={(indx) => swipeImage(indx)}/> //<<==here is the child DisplayImages. Imgs is a useState() which is an array of images. Its order will be changed if user drag and reorder the array.
                        </MyAccordion>
  )
```

Here is the console.output to show the order of images `Imgs` has been changed:

```
[Mon Sep 21 2020 23:17:49.624]  LOG       pics before move :  ["26689.1 (5-18-19) image 3.jpg", "4.jpg", "1.jpg"]
[Mon Sep 21 2020 23:17:49.626]  LOG      pics after move :  ["1.jpg", "26689.1 (5-18-19) image 3.jpg", "4.jpg"]
[Mon Sep 21 2020 23:17:49.626]  LOG      in updateImage ["1.jpg", "26689.1 (5-18-19) image 3.jpg", "4.jpg"] //<<==updateImage in DisplayImages calls setImgs to update the Imgs
```

With the update of state `Imgs`, component `DisplayImages` is expected to re-render. However it did not. Why update of state `Imgs` did not cause re-render?

UPDATE: `DisplayImages` component. `DisplayImages` is to display images in square grid which may have varied width by total number of images. Gesture handling is used to handle the drag and sort images. The code is  in dev and may be hard to read.

```
import React, { useRef, useMemo, useState, useContext} from 'react';
import {View, FlatList, Image, StyleSheet, ScrollView, TextInput, Platform, TouchableOpacity, SafeAreaView, Dimensions, TouchableWithoutFeedback } from 'react-native';
import { Col, Row, Grid } from 'react-native-easy-grid';
import { PanGestureHandler, PinchGestureHandler, State, RotationGestureHandler } from "react-native-gesture-handler";
import FastImage from "react-native-fast-image";
import Animated, { useValue } from "react-native-reanimated";
const {Value,event,cond,block,set,eq,add,abs,divide,multiply,not,clockRunning,and,or,greaterOrEq,startClock,stopClock,greaterThan,lessThan,call,Clock} = Animated;
import { propsContext} from "../app/GlobalContext";
//import {DeleteButton, GridImage, ModalImage, ModalImageAndroidWrap} from "./viewComponent";

const {width, height} = Dimensions.get("window");

//display images in Col based on number of images
export default DisplayImages = ({pics, deleteImage, updateImage, swipeImage}) => {
    //params 
    const propsVal = useContext(propsContext);
    const device_id=propsVal.device_id, screen_width=width, screen_ht=height;
    //const [tf, setTf] = useState(false);

    if (!pics || pics===[] || pics==={}) return null;
    var len = pics.length, full=0.98, half=0.49, oneThird=0.32; 
    
    console.log("# of images : ", len);
    //check if there is field domain in pics passed in
    const picPath = (item) => {
        if (item.domain) {
            return (item.domain + item.path);
        } else {
            return item.path;
        };
    };

    const move = (from, to) => {
        //
        console.log(" pics before move : ", pics.map((it) => it.fileName));
        var target = pics[from];                         
        var increment = to < from ? -1 : 0;
        pics.splice(from, 1);
        if (Math.abs(to-from)==1) {
            pics.splice(to,0, target);
        } else {
            pics.splice(to+increment<=0 ? 0:to+increment,0, target);
        };
        console.log("pics after move : ", pics.map((it) => it.fileName));
        updateImage(pics);
      }

    
    function DisplayImg ({img_source, width, ht, index, handleSwipe, modalWidth, modalHt, dataLen, sortFn=null}) {
        const aniIndex= new Value(index);
        const dragX = (useValue(0));
        const dragY = (useValue(0));
        const offsetX = new Value(0);
        const offsetY = new Value(0);
        var transX = useValue(0);
        var transY = useValue(0);
        const state = useValue(-1);
        const scale = useValue(1);
        const rotate = useValue(0);
        const offsetZ = useValue(1);
        var gridPerRow;
        console.log("image width : ", width);
        console.log("image ht : ", ht);
        if (dataLen <= 4 && dataLen > 1) {
            gridPerRow = 2;
        } else if (dataLen > 4) {
            gridPerRow = 3;
        } else {
            gridPerRow = 1;
        };
        const aniGridPR = new Value(gridPerRow);
        
                
        function onDrop ([x, y, indx, gridPR]) {
            console.log("x onDrop ", x);
            console.log("y onDrop ", y);
            console.log("index : ", index);
            console.log("Grid PR : ", gridPR);
            var jump_y=0, jump_x=0, new_index, percentage;
            //jump_row               
            jump_y = y>0 ? Math.floor(y/ht) : -Math.floor(-y/ht);
            percentage = Math.abs((y%ht)/ht);
            if (percentage >= 0.3) (y>0 ? jump_y++ : jump_y--); //count if Y overlap 30% or more
            console.log("Y jump : ", jump_y);
            //jump col
            jump_x = x>0 ? Math.floor(x/width) : -Math.floor(-x/width);
            //console.log("jump X : ", jump_x);
            percentage = Math.abs((x%width)/width);
            //console.log("col percentage : ", percentage);
            if (percentage >= 0.3) (x>0 ? jump_x++ : jump_x--); //count if X overlap 30% or more
            console.log("X jump : ", jump_x);
            new_index = indx + jump_y*gridPR + jump_x
            console.log("new index : ", new_index);
            if (new_index != indx) {
                sortFn(indx, new_index);
            };
        };
        if (img_source && img_source!==[] && img_source!=={}) {
            console.log("ani code");
            
            const addX = add(offsetX, dragX);
            const addY = add(offsetY, dragY);
            transX = cond(eq(state, State.ACTIVE), addX);
            transY = cond(eq(state, State.ACTIVE), addY, 
                                    cond(eq(state, State.END), 
                                        cond(or(greaterOrEq(abs(divide(dragX,new Value(width))), new Value(0.3)), greaterOrEq(abs(divide(dragY,new Value(ht))), new Value(0.3))), 
                                            call([addX, addY, aniIndex, aniGridPR], onDrop))
                                        )
                                    );
            //console.log("2", transY);
            const handleGesture = event([
                {
                    nativeEvent: {
                    translationX: dragX,
                    translationY: dragY,
                    state,
                    },
                }, 
                ]);
            
            let aniStyle = {
                transform:[
                    { translateX : transX },
                    { translateY : transY },
                    
                ]
            };
            let scaleStyle = {
                transform:[
                    { perspective: 500 },
                    {
                        scale :  scale
                    }
                ]
            };
            return (
                <>
                    
                    <PanGestureHandler 
                        onGestureEvent={handleGesture} 
                        onHandlerStateChange={handleGesture}
                        minPointers={1}
                        maxPointers={1}>
                        <Animated.View style={[aniStyle ]}>
                        <TouchableOpacity onLongPress={() => deleteImage(index)} onPress={()=>handleSwipe()} >
                            <Animated.View style={[styles.wrapper]}>
                                <FastImage 
                                    source={{uri:img_source}} 
                                    resizeMode={FastImage.resizeMode.cover} 
                                    style={[{
                                        width:width, 
                                        height:ht, 
                                        verticalAlign:0,
                                        paddingTop:0
                                    }]}
                                />
                            </Animated.View>
                        </TouchableOpacity> 
                        </Animated.View>
                    </PanGestureHandler>
        
                
                </>
                );
        
            
        } else {
            return null;
        };
        
    };    
    
    //if (len > 0) setImgAccordOpen(true);
    switch(len) {
        case 0:
            return null;
        case 1:
            
            return (
                <Grid style={{position:"absolute", paddingTop:0,paddingLeft:0}}>
                    <Row style={styles.row} key={pics[0].fileName}>
                    <DisplayImg 
                        img_source={picPath(pics[0])}
                        width={screen_width*full}
                        ht={screen_width*full}
                        index= {0}
                        modalWidth={screen_width}
                        modalHt= {pics[0].height*(screen_width/pics[0].width)}
                        dataLen={len}
                        sortFn={move}
                        handleSwipe={swipeImage} 
                    />                   
                    </Row>
                </Grid>
                );
        case 2:
        case 3: 
        case 4:
            
            return (
                <Grid style={{position:"absolute", paddingTop:0,paddingLeft:0}}>
                    {pics.map((item, index) => {
                        if (index%2===0) {  
                            if (pics[index+1]) {
                                return (
                                    <Row style={styles.row} key={pics[index].fileName+pics[index+1].fileName}>
                                        
                                        <DisplayImg 
                                            img_source={picPath(pics[index])}
                                            width={screen_width*half}
                                            ht={screen_width*half}
                                            index= {index}
                                            modalWidth={screen_width}
                                            modalHt= {pics[index].height*(screen_width/pics[index].width)}
                                            dataLen={len}
                                            sortFn={move}
                                            handleSwipe={swipeImage} 
                                        />
                                       
                                        <DisplayImg 
                                            img_source={picPath(pics[index+1])}
                                            width={screen_width*half}
                                            ht={screen_width*half}
                                            index= {index+1}
                                            modalWidth={screen_width}
                                            modalHt= {pics[index+1].height*(screen_width/pics[index+1].width)}
                                            dataLen={len}
                                            sortFn={move}
                                            handleSwipe={swipeImage} 
                                        />                                                                    
                                    </Row>
                                )} else {
                                return (
                                    <Row style={styles.row} key={pics[index].fileName}>
                                        <DisplayImg 
                                            img_source={picPath(pics[index])}
                                            width={screen_width*half}
                                            ht={screen_width*half}
                                            index= {index}
                                            modalWidth={screen_width}
                                            modalHt= {pics[index].height*(screen_width/pics[index].width)}
                                            dataLen={len}
                                            sortFn={move}
                                            handleSwipe={swipeImage} 
                                        />
                                        
                                    </Row>    
                                )};                                           
                        }
                    })}                        
                </Grid>
            );

        default:
            return (
                <Grid style={{position:"absolute", paddingTop:0,paddingLeft:0}}>
                    {pics.map((item, index) => {
                        if (index%3===0) {  
                            if (pics[index+2]) {
                                return (
                                    <Row style={styles.row} key={pics[index].fileName+pics[index+1].fileName+pics[index+2].fileName}>
                                        <DisplayImg 
                                            img_source={picPath(pics[index])}
                                            width={screen_width*oneThird}
                                            ht={screen_width*oneThird}
                                            index= {index}
                                            modalWidth={screen_width}
                                            modalHt= {pics[index].height*(screen_width/pics[index].width)}
                                            dataLen={len}
                                            sortFn={move}
                                            handleSwipe={swipeImage}
                                            
                                        />
                                        <DisplayImg 
                                            img_source={picPath(pics[index+1])}
                                            width={screen_width*oneThird}
                                            ht={screen_width*oneThird}
                                            index= {index+1}
                                            modalWidth={screen_width}
                                            modalHt= {pics[index+1].height*(screen_width/pics[index+1].width)}
                                            dataLen={len}
                                            sortFn={move}
                                            handleSwipe={swipeImage}
                                           
                                        />
                                        <DisplayImg 
                                            img_source={picPath(pics[index+2])}
                                            width={screen_width*oneThird}
                                            ht={screen_width*oneThird}
                                            index= {index+2}
                                            modalWidth={screen_width}
                                            modalHt= {pics[index+2].height*(screen_width/pics[index+2].width)}
                                            dataLen={len}
                                            sortFn={move}
                                            handleSwipe={swipeImage}
                                            
                                        />
                                        
                                    </Row>    
                            )} else if (pics[index+1]) {
                                return (
                                    <Row style={styles.row} key={pics[index].fileName+pics[index+1].fileName}>
                                        <DisplayImg 
                                            img_source={picPath(pics[index])}
                                            width={screen_width*oneThird}
                                            ht={screen_width*oneThird}
                                            index= {index}
                                            modalWidth={screen_width}
                                            modalHt= {pics[index].height*(screen_width/pics[index].width)}
                                            dataLen={len}
                                            sortFn={move}
                                            handleSwipe={swipeImage}
                                            
                                        />
                                        <DisplayImg 
                                            img_source={picPath(pics[index+1])}
                                            width={screen_width*oneThird}
                                            ht={screen_width*oneThird}
                                            index= {index+1}
                                            modalWidth={screen_width}
                                            modalHt= {pics[index+1].height*(screen_width/pics[index+1].width)}
                                            dataLen={len}
                                            sortFn={move}
                                            handleSwipe={swipeImage}
                                            
                                        />
                                    </Row>    
                            )} else if (!pics[index+1]) {
                                return (
                                    <Row style={styles.row} key={pics[index].fileName}>
                                        <DisplayImg 
                                            img_source={picPath(pics[index])}
                                            width={screen_width*oneThird}
                                            ht={screen_width*oneThird}
                                            index= {index}
                                            modalWidth={screen_width}
                                            modalHt= {pics[index].height*(screen_width/pics[index].width)}
                                            dataLen={len}
                                            sortFn={move}
                                            handleSwipe={swipeImage}
                                           
                                        />
                                    </Row>
                            )} else {
                                return null;
                            };                                           
                        }
                    })}                        
                </Grid>
            );

        };        
        
};
```

Comment: Please post code from ```DisplayImages``` component.

Comment: `SaachiTech`, posted the component. The code is in dev and may be messy. Thanks.

Comment: Is it because 2 arrays with the exactly same elements but different order are the same in javascript?

Comment: After adding a state `flip` flip={flip} and setFlip(!flip) in `updateImages`, re-render starts to work.

Answer (score 2):

React.memo  function which can be used to determine if a component should render or not in hooks
if the function returns true then component won't re-render on change of that prop, conversely it updates when the return value is false

```
function Itie({prop1, prop2}) {
    return(
        ..
    )

}
React.memo(Itie, (props, nextProps)=> {
    if(props.prop1 === nextProps.prop1) {
        // don't re-render/update
        return true
    }
    
})
```

Answer (score 0):

The no-render problem may be caused by 2 arrays with exactly the same elements but different order is treated same in Javascript. To force re-render, a boolean state `flip` is added to component `Itie`. Whenever there is order change with image array, `flip` changes its value which trigger the re-render. Here is the related code:

```
export default function Itie({navigation}) {
    const [flip, setFlip] = useState(false);
    //do something
    return (
         <MyAccordion 
              title={"Image"} 
              absPosition={false} 
              screenSize={{width:screen_width, height:((imgs && imgs.length>9) ? screen_width+(screen_width/3)*(Math.ceil(((imgs.length-9)%3)/3)):screen_width)}} 
              ref= {refImg}
                        >
               <DisplayImages pics={imgs} deleteImage={deleteImage} flip={flip} updateImage={(new_img) => {setImgs(new_img);setFlip(!flip);}} swipeImage={swipeImage}/> 
          </MyAccordion>
)
```

Comment: If the array isn’t holding big data, you may create a new array like [...lastarray], this will be new array instance and cause the re-render as well.